# Plot bar graph and timeseries plot on different axis using pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that is read in from a .csv file with this structure:

```
Date,       Latitude,   Longitude,        Brand,        Pump, AKI,  Trip Miles,  Total Miles, Gallons,  MPG,    PPG,    Total,  Tires,  MPG-D,
11/03/2013, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  2,    87,   134.3,       134.3,       6.563,    20.46,  3.319,  21.78,  Stock,  ,
11/17/2013, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  2,    87,   161.8,       296.0,       7.467,    21.67,  3.279,  24.48,  Stock,  ,
11/27/2013, 40° 0.872', -105° 12.775',    Buffalo Gas,  6,    87,   180.8,       477.0,       8.096,    22.33,  3.359,  27.19,  Stock,  ,
12/07/2013, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  6,    87,   265.1,       742.0,       12.073,   21.96,  3.179,  38.38,  Stock,  ,
12/11/2013, 40° 2.170', -105° 15.522',    Circle K,     4,    87,   240.9,       983.0,       9.868,    24.41,  3.179,  31.37,  Stock,  ,
12/15/2013, 40° 8.995', -105° 7.876',     Shell,        3,    87,   188.7,       1172,        8.596,    21.95,  3.059,  26.30,  ,       ,
12/21/2013, 40° 1.770', -105° 15.481',    Conoco,       3,    87,   113.8,       1286,        5.517,    20.62,  3.139,  17.32,  Winter, ,
01/09/2014, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  2,    87,   139.5,       1426,        7.181,    19.42,  3.279,  23.55,  Winter, 21.3,
01/13/2013, 40° 1.770', -105° 15.481',    Conoco,       7,    87,   260.8,       1688,        11.177,   23.33,  3.239,  36.20,  Winter, 25.5,
01/18/2014, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  2,    87,   102.0,       1790,        4.401,    23.18,  3.239,  14.26,  Winter, 25.5,
02/02/2014, 39° 59.132', -105° 14.962',   King Soopers, 5,    87,   175.3,       1965,        8.436,    20.78,  3.019,  25.47,  Winter, 24.0,
02/03/2014, 40° 1.770', -105° 15.481',    Conoco,       3,    87,   249.9,       2215,        10.452,   23.91,  3.219,  33.64,  Winter, 25.2,
02/08/2014, 40° 2.170', -105° 15.522',    Circle K,     7,    87,   186.4,       2402,        8.565,    21.76,  3.239,  27.74,  Winter, 24.3,
02/13/2014, 40° 1.729', -105° 15.516',    Boulder Gas,  8,    87,    79.6,       2481,        4.125,    19.30,  3.439,  14.19,  Winter, 21.3,
03/06/2014, 40.014460, -105.225034,       Conoco,       5,    87,   172.4,       2654,        8.618,    20.00,  3.779,  32.57,  Winter, 21.9,
03/09/2014, 40.029498, -105.258117,       Conoco,       6,    87,   230.4,       2884,        9.016,    25.55,  3.759,  33.89,  Winter, 27.3,
03/17/2014, 40.036236, -105.258763,       Conoco,       6,    87,   130.1,       3014,        5.368,    24.24,  3.719,  19.96,  Winter, 25.8,
03/24/2014, 40.036236, -105.258763,       Conoco,       1,    87,   282.3,       3297,       11.540,    24.46,  3.719,  42.92,  Winter, 27.3,
```

I want to produce a plot where the x-axis is the date, the left y-axis is miles/gallon, and the right y-axis is Miles.  In this plot I want to show a time series for the 'MPG' column in one color, time series for 'MPG-D' in another color and a bar graph of the 'Trip Miles' column in a third color.

I have been trying to follow http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html and have the code below but it produces a bar plot and both time series plots where everything is on the same axis and the y-label is not shown.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv', skipinitialspace=True,index_col='Date')
plt.figure()
ax = data['Trip Miles'].plot(kind='bar',secondary_y=['Trip Miles'])
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Miles')
ax.set_ylabel('Miles/Gallon')
data['MPG'].plot()
data['MPG-D'].plot()
```

[image: plot I get from above code]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify the axes more explicitly. Try it like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, tsax = plt.subplots()
barax = tsax.twinx()

data = pd.read_csv('mpg.csv', skipinitialspace=True,index_col='Date')
data['Trip Miles'].plot(kind='bar', ax=barax)
barax.set_ylabel('Miles')
tsax.set_ylabel('Miles/Gallon')
data['MPG'].plot(ax=tsax)
data['MPG-D'].plot(ax=tsax)
```

### Edit

So a big problem here is that pandas bar plots and line plots format the x-axis in fundamentally different ways. Specifically, bar plots attempt to make qualitative scales with ticks and labels for every single bar. But it seems here that you're interested in a getting a format more like a typical time series.

So here's where I suggest that you forget about dual axis charts. Instead, just plot on two completely separate axes. Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as mgrid
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
grid = mgrid.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, height_ratios=[2, 1])

barax = fig.add_subplot(grid[0])
tsax = fig.add_subplot(grid[1])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('ABC'), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='1M', start='2012-01-01', periods=10))

data['A'] **= 2
data['A'].plot(ax=barax, style='o--')
barax.set_ylabel('Miles')
tsax.set_ylabel('Miles/Gallon')

barax.xaxis.tick_top()

data['B'].plot(ax=tsax)
data['C'].plot(ax=tsax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

Which gives me:
[image: separate axes]

However, if you *really* need bars or you *really* want everything on the same twin x-axes, then you have to plot with matplotlib's API like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as mgrid
import pandas as pd

fig, tsax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
barax = tsax.twinx()

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('ABC'), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(freq='1M', start='2012-01-01', periods=10))
data['A'] **= 2

# the `width` is specified in days -- adjust for your data
barax.bar(data.index, data['A'], width=5, facecolor='indianred')

barax.set_ylabel('Miles')
tsax.set_ylabel('Miles/Gallon')

barax.xaxis.tick_top()

fig.tight_layout()

tsax.plot(data.index, data['B'])
tsax.plot(data.index, data['C'])
```

Which then gives me

[image: single axes]

Comment: How can I get it to display the dates along the x-axis?

Comment: @DeltaP can you post more rows of your data? trim out the columns we don't need and keep it in the csv format, please.

Comment: I've included the whole file.  I'd rather not trim the unnecessary columns because they will be necessary for other things.  In terms of csv format...I'm assuming you mean to remove the spaces?  That really isn't necessary since all the functions I've encountered have methods to remove initial spaces.

Comment: @DeltaP The difference here is that SO isn't concerned with achieving your end result, just in informing you *how* to achieve your end result. So for these purposes, a minimal working example, aka http://www.sscce.org/, is better to include, as I did in my examples.