# bar plot is different from line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot two graphs on the same plot with a secondatu axis.

I am trying to plot the dataframe:

```
    conversion_rate population
1   0.0002  1175000
2   0.0003  179000
3   0.0006  27000
4   0.0009  6000
```

This code is gives me the relationship between values:

```
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = agg['population'].plot(ylim=[0, 1200000], colormap=cm.Pastel1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

agg['conversion_rate'].plot(alpha=0.5, linestyle='-', marker='o', ylim=[0, 0.001], color='green', secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I want to convert one of the to a kind='bar' plot:

```
fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = agg['population'].plot(kind='bar', xlim=[-0.5,4.5], ylim=[0, 1200000], colormap=cm.Pastel1)

ax2 = ax.twinx()

agg['conversion_rate'].plot(alpha=0.5, linestyle='-', marker='o', xlim=[-0.5,4.5], ylim=[0, 0.001], color='green', secondary_y=True)

plt.show()
```

I get:

[image]

Line plot gets and offset of 1 to the right.

Any ideas how to do it right / correct the bar plot?

Comment: The problem is that bar charts are treated as categorical data, with the x axis in the range from 0 .. n-1. Line charts are typically treated as continuous data, with the x axis as specified (in this case from 1 .. n). Which is why one series is off by one to the other series. This question has been answered a few times already. Look for twinx().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plot bar graph and timeseries plot on different axis using pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623324/plot-bar-graph-and-timeseries-plot-on-different-axis-using-pandas)